# How hanuman ji killed akshayakumar if kaal was imprisoned in ravana's prison

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, ravana

Ravana had tied all nav-grahas and also imprisoned kaal. Is it true then that kaal can't take anyone's life in ravan's kingdom without his permission? If yes, then how Hanuman Ji killed Akshayakumar in Ashok Vatika because Hanuman Ji freed kaal when he was burning Lanka.

Comment: There is no story of Kaal being imprisoned in Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: @GokulRenjith Yes, I think it is occured from any serial or it is a folklore.